# State hoisting for each item in LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, state, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I've gone through [this](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#6)  codelab. In step number 7, when clicking on single row's text it's changing its color, but function will not keep track of it, meaning it will disappear after re-composition.

I want list to remember color of single item thus I've move state hoisting  to the NameList function level.
Unfortunately it's not working.

Where's the bug?

```
    @Composable
fun NameList(names: List<String>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
        items(items = names) { name, ->
            val isSelected  = remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
            Greeting(name = name,isSelected.value){ newSelected -> isSelected.value = newSelected}
            Divider(color = Color.Black)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String,isSelected : Boolean, updateSelected : (Boolean) -> Unit) {

    val backgroundColor by animateColorAsState(if (isSelected) Color.Red else Color.Transparent)
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(24.dp)
            .background(color = backgroundColor)
            .clickable(onClick = { updateSelected(!isSelected)}),
        text = "Hello $name",

        )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should hoist your selection state to the caller of `NameList` function.

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    // Fake list of names
    val namesList = (1..100).map { "Item $it" }
    // Here, we're keeping the selected positions. 
    // At the beginning, all names are not selected.
    val selection = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(*namesList.map { false }.toTypedArray())
    }
    
    NameList(
        // list of names
        names = namesList, 
        // list of selected items
        selectedItems = selection,
        // this function will update the list above
        onSelected = { index, selected -> selection[index] = selected },
        // just to occupy the whole screen 
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
}
```

Then, your `NameList` will look like this:

```
@Composable
fun NameList(
    names: List<String>,
    selectedItems: List<Boolean>,
    onSelected: (index: Int, selected: Boolean) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
        itemsIndexed(items = names) { index, name ->
            Greeting(
                name = name, 
                isSelected = selectedItems[index],
                updateSelected = { onSelected(index, it) }
            )
            Divider(color = Color.Black)
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing changes on `Greeting` function.

Here is the result:

[image]